# Add and remove array items from array list using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, push, splice

I would like to establish a function where you can add and remove users

1. to comma separated string which is stored in an input field and
2. Show the list of added users in html to delete each line item if needed.

Unfortunately I have the following issues in my code:

1. The comma separated userlist +  html list adds the user to each new created line item
2. Deleting one line item from HTML list doesn't work as expected.

[image]

**Expected result:**

***input value:*** Adam,Bertha,Caesar

***html value:***

Adam (delete)

Bertha (delete)

Caesar (delete)

Could you please have a look at my [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fkuhrt/ek2mavfd/64/) and give me a hint how to display the userlist correctly in html + input field?

```js
var users = [];

$("#adddis").click(function() {
  var values = $('input[type=text]').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get().join();
  $('#adddisnames').val("");
  addUser(values);
});

function buildUserlist() {

  var html = "<hr>";
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    html += users[i] + ' <a href="#" onclick="removeUser(' + i + '); return false;">X</a><br>';
  };
  $('#userdiv').html(html);
}

function addUser(values) {
  users.push(values);
  buildUserlist();
  $('#storadddis').val(users);
}

function removeUser(index) {
  users.splice(index, 1);
  buildUserlist();
  $('#storadddis').val(users);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" id="adddisnames" value="">
<input type="button" name="get_value" id="adddis" value="add"> =>
<input type="text" id="storadddis" size="35">
<div id="userdiv"></div>
```

Comment: `var values = $('input[type=text]').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get().join();` why? You are getting users from all input fields on the page including storaddis.

Comment: Just have `$("#adddis").click(function() {
  var value = $('#adddisnames').val();
  if (value) addUser(value);
});`

Comment: Feel free to delete the question

Comment: Do you know how to check if user is already stored in array and prevent saving redundant user?

Comment: `function addUser(values) {
  if (users.indexOf(values) !=-1) return;
 users.push(values);
  buildUserlist();
  $('#storadddis').val(users);
}`

Answer (score 1):

**First : Change this code to this**

```
 $("#adddis").click(function() {
     if ($('#adddisnames').val().length !== 0) {
       addItem($('#adddisnames').val());
     } else {
        alert ('Please add User!')
     }
});
```

**Next : change this code also  to this**

```
function addItem(values) {
  users.push(values);
  buildUserlist();
  $('#storadddis').val(users.toString());
  $('#adddisnames').val("");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `users` array as the master of the data. When adding names, don't take that `input` value together with what is in the rightmost `input`. Consider the text in that rightmost control as an *output*, not as input.

As you use jQuery, I would also use jQuery to the full for populating the `div` element. This way you are also sure that any characters in the usernames, that could be misinterpreted as HTML, are properly escaped.

For the click handler: it is probably better to use event delegation, and only define one click handler on the `div` element, *once*. You can know which link was clicked with the `.index()` jQuery method.

```js
var users = [];

$("#adddis").click(function() {
    addUser($('#adddisnames').val().split(",")); // pass an array as argument
    $('#adddisnames').val("");
});

$('#userdiv').on("click", "a", function () { // event delegation
    removeUser($(this).parent().index());
});

function buildUserlist() {
    // Use jQuery functions to build the DOM list:
    $('#userdiv').empty().append(
        users.map(function (user) {
            return $("<div>").text(user).append($("<a>").attr("href", "#").text("✘"));
        })
    );
    $('#storadddis').val(users); // do this here -- as it is part of the output
}

function addUser(values) { // Expect an array as argument here
    values = values.map(value => value.trim()) // trim values
                   .filter(Boolean); // ... and exclude empty entries
    users = users.concat(values);  // join the two arrays
    users = Array.from(new Set(users)); // make list unique
    
    buildUserlist();
}

function removeUser(index) {
    users.splice(index, 1);
    buildUserlist();
}
```

```css
a[href] {
    color:red;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" id="adddisnames" value="">
<input type="button" name="get_value" id="adddis" value="add"> =>
<input type="text" id="storadddis" size="35">
<div id="userdiv"></div>
```

Comment: This is really much better than my try to code this function. Many thanks for the detailed comments on the code. I learned much from you. I'm happy with the functions. The only thing I have to figure out is to prevent adding duplicate users to the array.

Comment: You can use `Set` to create a unique list. I added one line of code for this.

Comment: okay, cool. But when submitting an empty value it creates a "x" Symbol. Have to check if values is not empty when add is clicked then it works like a charm.

`$"#adddis").click(function() {
    var value = $('#adddisnames').val();
    if (value) {
        addUser(value.split(",")); // pass an array as argument
        $('#adddisnames').val("");
    }
});`

Comment: I added two lines of code to trim spaces around names, and discard empty entries (like when you have two commas next to eachother).

Answer (score -1):

without Telling you to update everything to make it cleaner.  I think your simple fix is to update this line:

```
var values = $('input[type=text]').map(function() {
```

To

```
var values = $('input[id=adddisnames]').map(function() {
```

The way you had it before is it was finding both input fields, and then duplicating your results

Comment: Yeah right, this caused the problem. Fixed it and it worked. Tks

Comment: not sure why this got down voted when it fixed the problem